# Warning: Error creating LLDB target at some path

Tags: console, warnings, lldb, xcode6.1, ios8.1

I'm running an application on Xcode 6.1 and iPhone (iOS 8.1) simulator. While running I'm getting below log on console window :

```
Warning: Error creating LLDB target at path '/Users/macbook/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/..Project.app'- 
using an empty LLDB target which can cause slow memory reads from remote devices.
```

If I run app in Xcode 5.x and iPhone (iOS 7.x) simulator then there is no such log on console.
What might be reason? Will there be an issue if I upload app to app-store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning is solved by changing Build Settings :

1. Select Project -> Build Settings
2. Change **'Architectures' to 'Standard architectures (armv7, arm64) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)'**
   [image: Step 2]
3. This will prompt an alert stating iOS 5.1.1 and above are supported. Click **'Change Deployment Target to 5.1.1'**

[image: Step 3]

4. Repeat steps for Target (if not changed automatically)

[image: Step 4]

Also, this is preferred build setting since Apple is forcing developers to build apps on 64 bit architecture. [Apple document Link](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12172014b)

Answer (score 6):

This warning is primarily intended for iOS device debugging.  In that environment, Xcode copies the device's libraries and frameworks up to the Mac and saves them in a directory for lldb.  When you start the debug session and lldb sees that the Foundation framework is being used by your app, it can read the copy on the Mac -- otherwise it would have to read the copy out of memory from the iOS debug session which is slow.

Why you're seeing this with some of your simulator debug configurations, I can't say; it's not expected.  But for a Mac native process debug session (like you're doing with iOS Simulator debugging), it is harmless - the performance cost of lldb reading it out of local mac memory is very small.

It definitely won't have any affect on your app when uploaded to the store.  This is an entirely Xcode/lldb cacheing issue, nothing to do with your app.

Answer (score 1):

It causes when you use Architectures=$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) and run your app on a 64 bit device.

It can be solved by setting 'Architectures' to 'Standard architectures (armv7, arm64) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)' in build settings

Answer (score 0):

So is it ok to submit app to app store while you are getting this warning in debugging on iPhone 5S or latest device/simulator ? I heard that apple can reject your app if you don't upgrade to 64bit arch without any good reason.

Any ways -
 The solution for this warning is to Standard Architectures(armv7,arm64) rather then $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)

But keep in mind that it will only support your app if all your pods, frameworks also support this or you would have to upgrade them. (Some time its not a quick thing to do.)

Vishnu

Answer (score 0):

This *"Error creating LLDB target at path … - using an empty LLDB target"* can also occur with the `x86_64` to `arm64` transition. This is the case where an Apple Silicon computer builds for the `x86_64` architecture when the Simulator can run `arm64`.

The following was used to investigate and resolves the `…using an empty LLDB target…` error for Xcode 15 and the associated iPhone Simulator:

Use `file` to check the archicture of the build executable. The build folder can be located with the **Product** > **Show Build Folder in Finder** menu.

```bash
pwd
# …path/to/Build
cd Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ExampleName.app

file ExampleName
# Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64

### x86_64 can raise the empty LLDB target error when debugging
### iOS in the Simulator on an Apple Silicon computer.
```

*.xcodeproj Settings*

| Title | Name | Debug | Release |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Architectures | `ARCHS` | default: `$(ARCHS_STANDARD)` | default: `$(ARCHS_STANDARD)` |
| Excluded Architectures | `EXCLUDED_ARCHS` | unset | unset |
| Build Active Architectures Only | `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH` | Yes | default: No |

*CocoaPods Podfile*

```rb
### other: `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH` = YES only for `*Debug*` configurations
if config.name.include?("Debug")
    config.build_settings["ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH"] = "NO"
end
```

*debug.xcconfig*

As FYI, the `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH` setting can be added to `*.xcconfig` files for both implementation and documentation purposes.

```ini
// Resolve "Error creating LLDB target … using an empty LLDB target…"
ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = YES
```